# Macでテキスト入力時に、システムのショートカットキー(Shift+Cmd+4等)が動作するのを防ぐ方法はないでしょうか？

Tags: swift, macos

macOS10.15でテキスト(TextFilet)のキー入力をキャプチャするアプリ(Swift)を作っていますが、システムのショートカットキーに登録されているキーを押した場合に、ショートカットの機能が動作してしまいます。
アプリでショートカットの機能を防止する方法はないでしょうか？

[ショートカットキー　例]
・Shift + Cmd +4 → 画面キャプチャが動作する
・Control + space → 入力切替が動作する
・Command + space → スポットライトが動作する

ショートカット押下時は、keyDown()も呼ばれないため、対応手段が見当たりません。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。

CGEvent.tapCreate()を使用することで、キーボードの入力イベントをすべて無効にすることができました。